# get tokens balance

Tags: spl, balance

Looking for a way to fetch owner tokens and balance.
i have tried the following code:

```
 const tokenAccounts = await this.solanaUtilService.connection.getTokenAccountsByOwner(
  this.wallet.publicKey,
  {
    programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
  }
);

console.log("Token                                         Balance");
console.log("------------------------------------------------------------");
tokenAccounts.value.forEach(async (tokenAccount) => {
  const accountData = AccountLayout.decode(tokenAccount.account.data);
  console.log(`${new PublicKey(accountData.mint)}  AMOUNT  ${accountData.amount}`);
  let tokenAmount = await this.solanaUtilService.connection.getTokenAccountBalance(new PublicKey(accountData.mint));
  console.log(tokenAmount)
})
```

also tried:

```
public async getTokensAccountbyOwner(publicKey: PublicKey) {
    const accounts = await this.connection.getParsedProgramAccounts(
      TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, // new PublicKey("TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA")
      {
        filters: [
          {
            dataSize: 165, // number of bytes
          },
          {
            memcmp: {
              offset: 32, // number of bytes
              bytes: publicKey.toBase58(), // base58 encoded string
            },
          },
        ],
      })
    return accounts;
  }
    const splAccounts = await this.solanaUtilsService.getTokensAccountbyOwner(this.wallet.publicKey);
    splAccounts.filter(async spl =>{
       const tokenAddress = spl.account.data['parsed'].info.mint
       let tokenAmount = await this.solanaUtilService.connection.getTokenAccountBalance(new PublicKey(tokenAddress));
      console.log(tokenAmount)
      });
```

both didn't work...
any suggestions?

Comment: what "didn't work"?  error? no results? something else? help us help you

Comment: We need the output you got (including error messages), and the out put you expected. That gives us a chance to help with your issues.

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
/**
 * Returns the balance of a token account, in whatever currency the account is in.
 * @param program
 * @param account
 * @returns
 */
export const getTokenAccountBalance = async (
  program: Program,
  account: PublicKey
) => {
  let accountInfo = await program.provider.connection.getAccountInfo(account);
  let data = AccountLayout.decode(accountInfo.data);

  return Number(data.amount);
};
```

You can also use the spl-token 2 library, like this:

```
  let accountData = await getAccount(program.provider.connection, account, "confirmed");
  return accountData.amount;
```

Comment: for the first suggestion-  err when using getAccountInfo:
RangeError: Trying to access beyond buffer length

for the second  suggestion-  i dont see exported getAccount fn on "@solana/spl-token"

Comment: The first one will fail if the account is not a token account. The second one was called as Token.getAccount() prior to spl-token 2.0, so use that if you are on spl-token <2, or see https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/modules.html#getAccount for 2.0+